# XPath select wsdl prefix namespaces

Tags: java, xml, soap, xpath, wsdl

I am using XPath 1.0 in java and would like to select/check wsdl document namespaces, but unfortunately did not managed to do it.
I would like to select

1. Namespace xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" represented as
   attribute of "definitions" element
2. Namespace xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" represented as attribute of "definitions" element.

I tried XPath expressions:

1. "//namespace:: * " and "/*/namespace:: * ", which seem to be mystic,
   because they return:

   ```
   "http: //www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", 
   "http: //www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" ????? (where does it come from?)
   ```
2. "/definitions/@*" returns:

   ```
   HelloService
   "http ://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   ```

Is there any way to catch xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" and xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" attributes/namespaces in this document using XPath? or maybe some other tools? to check if node(attribute) or namespace value is equal to schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap (kind of correct namespace control)

```
Wsdl document:
<definitions name="HelloService"
   targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name="SayHelloRequest">
      <part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <message name="SayHelloResponse">
      <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <portType name="Hello_PortType">
      <operation name="sayHello">
         <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
   <soap:binding style="rpc"
      transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   <operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
      <input>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </input>
      <output>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </output>
   </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/"/>
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:

```
/*/namespace::*[name()='']
```

Result:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/

For the second one:

```
/*/namespace::*[name()='soap']
```

Result:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/

You should remember to enable namespace support in java:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true); //This is really important, without it that XPath does not work
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(inputSource); //inputSource, inputStream or file which contains your XML.
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String nameSpace = xpath.evaluate("/*/namespace::*[name()='']", document);
String soapNameSpace = xpath.evaluate("/*/namespace::*[name()='soap']", document);
```

Comment: Does not work. Are you sure it should work with Xpath 1.0?                           NodeList result = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/*/namespace::*[name()='soap']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); and /*/namespace::*[name()=''] return nothing.

Comment: I've tested it in  http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath . It does not return a NodeList. I updated the answer to show the result of each one.

Comment: It works in XPath 1.0. The problem is that you did not enable the namespace in java DocumentBuilderFactory and the default value of it is false. I'm gonna update my answer with some java code to show you.

Comment: Ok, thanks) now it works! But where does http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace come from?

Comment: @user34618 That's a good question! This URI is a namespace that is _implicit_ to XML documents. It is the namespace for default attributes like `xml:id` and `xml:space`, but there is no need to redeclare this namespace in applications or in an XML document since it's a built-in declaration.

Comment: @user34618 . Good, as it works, the click on the 'v' option by the left side of the answer to mark the question as correct, so that others can find out that there is a correct question in it when looking for the same answer. Thanks

Comment: It works, but i actually wanted to check if node(attribute) or namespace value is equal to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/ and to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/, like /definitions/@xmlns="123".(kind of correct namespace control). Is it possible to do by Xpath 1.0?

Comment: Ok. /*/namespace::*[name()='' and .='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'] seems to work. Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: In addition, "dbf.setNamespaceAware(true)" requires now to use some namespace prefixes in xpath node select, so previously used "/definition" node can not be found, so i must use /*[local-name() = 'definitions'], the last one does not look very nice